# Finding a point on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Given three points that create a plane and its normal, find a point $P_0$ such that 
**$(P_i−P_0)·n= 0$**

How do you solve for $P_0$?

Comment: have you given concrete points?

Comment: What is your attempt? May we see it?

Comment: no, concrete points are not given @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: @PalautotKa not sure how to go about it at all.

Comment: What does $P_i$ stand for?

Comment: Pi stands for one of the three points

Comment: Any point $P_0$ in the plane has this property. Normal vector $n$ is orthogonal to the plane and thus to any distance vector between two points within the plane. Product of two orthogonal vectors equals to $0$.